# Pergunta sobre "OS X Speech Synthesis Manager" seria on-topic?

Tags: debate, perguntas, pergunta-específica, razões-fechamento

Votei para fechar esta pergunta como duplicata [Gerenciador de comandos de voz Siri](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202502/3635), pois no corpo da pergunta o autor diz isto (apesar do titulo dizer uma coisa que soa diferente):

> Gostaria de saber se existe alguma API ou alguma biblioteca que trabalhe com isso em python.

Então a pergunta que linkei aponta justamente **uma** API em Python que trabalha com `tts`, o [`pyttsx` na resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/161812/3635), o AP me [respondeu isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202502/gerenciador-de-comandos-de-voz-siri/202504#comment414872_202502):

> Nao e uma duplicata. Nesse post, ele pergunta se e possivel fazer um tts. Eu sei que e possivel e fiz em javascript. Quero saber se existe algum gerenciador que trabalhe com o say do OSX

E o autor da resposta [isto](http://@GuilhermeNascimento%20n%C3%A3o%20esta%20pedindo%20um%20software%20e%20sim%20um%20reposit%C3%B3rio%20ou%20plugin.):

> não esta pedindo um software e sim um repositório ou plugin.

Fora outro usuário [comentou algo parecido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202502/gerenciador-de-comandos-de-voz-siri/202504#comment415091_202504)

> Não considero off topic nem repetido

Não entendo de Mac OSX o suficiente para dizer se a pergunta é on ou off ou duplicata, então como foi mais de uma pessoa rebatendo preferi trazer o debate para cá.

De qualquer forma "a resposta" não parece ser muito útil pois não chega a orientar sobre o uso do conteúdo do link.

**Outra coisa que eu não entendi** foi o fechamento como *Ampla demais*, tá certo que a pergunta parece pedir duas coisas diferentes, mas ela soa bem mais confusa do que ampla, ao meu ver se não é *Duplicata* é *Off-topic*, se não dá para determinar se é um ou outro então o fechamento apropriado teria sido *"Não esta clara o suficiente"*

Comment: Eu concordo contigo. Independente do que *realmente* o AP queria, na maneira que a pergunta foi redigida é duplicata.